# combine cocoa uiview custom extension does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gesture, combine

I don't know why my extension UIView tabPublisher does not work.

I read swift combine cocoa library. and wanted to make UIView extension.(Swift combine cocoa does not give about UIView extension. )

Another example about custom uiview extension, the post make uiview extension using throttle. But I make it no sense.

[image]

```swift
extension Combine.Publishers {
    struct CustomTarget<Control: AnyObject>: Publisher {
        // swiftlint: disable nesting
        typealias Output = Void
        typealias Failure = Never
        // swiftlint: enable nesting
        let control: Control
        let addTargetAction: (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void
        let removeTargetAction: (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void
        
        init(
            control: Control,
            addTargetAction: @escaping (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void,
            removeTargetAction: @escaping (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void) {
            self.control = control
            self.addTargetAction = addTargetAction
            self.removeTargetAction = removeTargetAction
        }
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, S.Failure == Failure, S.Input == Output {
            let subscription = Subscription(
                subscriber: subscriber,
                control: control,
                addTargetAction: addTargetAction,
                removeTargetAction: removeTargetAction)
            subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
        }
    }
}

extension Combine.Publishers.CustomTarget {
    class Subscription<S: Subscriber, Control: AnyObject>: Combine.Subscription where S.Input == Void {
        private var subscriber: S?
        weak private var control: Control?
        
        let removeTargetAction: (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void
        let action = #selector(handleAction)
        
        init(
            subscriber: S,
            control: Control,
            addTargetAction: @escaping (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void,
            removeTargetAction: @escaping (Control, AnyObject, Selector) -> Void) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            self.control = control
            self.removeTargetAction = removeTargetAction
            addTargetAction(control, self, action)
        }
        
        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            
        }
        
        func cancel() {
            subscriber = nil
            removeTargetAction(control!, self, action)
        }
        
        @objc func handleAction() {
            _ = subscriber?.receive()
        }
    }
}

extension UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var tabGesturePublisher: AnyPublisher<UITapGestureRecognizer, Never> {
        gesturePublisher(for: self)
    }
}

private func gesturePublisher<Gesture: UIGestureRecognizer>(for gesture: Gesture) -> AnyPublisher<Gesture, Never> {
    Publishers.CustomTarget(
        control: gesture,
        addTargetAction: { gesture, target, action in
            gesture.addTarget(target, action: action)},
        removeTargetAction: { gesture, target, action in
            gesture.removeTarget(target, action: action)
        })
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .map { gesture }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Above codes exist in the combine cocoa exist
https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineCocoa/blob/main/Sources/CombineCocoa/CombineControlTarget.swift

Below codes are my custom UIView extension.

```swift
extension UIView {
    var tabPublisher: AnyPublisher<UITapGestureRecognizer, Never> { // this is problem
        UITapGestureRecognizer().tabGesturePublisher
    }
}
```

What's the problem in my code?
the gesture does not works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for might be the following:

```
extension UIView {
    var tapPublisher: AnyPublisher<UITapGestureRecognizer, Never> {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        return recognizer.tabGesturePublisher
    }
}
```

What you did in your case was

```
var tabPublisher: AnyPublisher<UITapGestureRecognizer, Never> { // this is problem
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    return recognizer.tabGesturePublisher
}
```

you created a gesture recognizer but did not associate it with the current view. It is missing `self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)`. So the gesture recognizer would never trigger and it would actually deallocate as soon as the method executes since there is nothing retaining it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this code attach gesture and detach every time when tap event called. Rght?

Comment: @안은노 Not every time when tap event is called. But it will attach a new gesture every time that `tapPublisher` is called. So it should be called only once per view in most cases.